# Probability of winning Tennis Point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hoping someone could help me with this..

The below equation is the probability of winning a tennis game 'k' given the probability of winning a point 'p'.

$$k=\frac{p^4(15-34 p +28 p^2-8p^3)}{1-2p+2p^2}$$

However I need to reverse this and make p the subject. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank You

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I am looking to rearrange the formula so that it would be p=....

Comment: It looks like you'll end up having to solve a degree 7 polynomial so there may well not be an expression in radicals, particularly as the k means you'll not just be trying to solve one of them but a whole class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's going to be a nice formula.  There must be some formula, as we have polynomials of degree at most $4$, but nice ones?

Just solve numerically if you want to know which $p$ gives a game probability with some given value.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the numerator is seventh degree I would not look for an analytic solution and turn to numerics instead.  The very flat regions below $0.2$ and above $0.8$ make me think of bisection.  A plot of your equation is below.
[image]
I made a spreadsheet and it converges quickly.  For example, $k=0.3$ gives $p \approx 0.4166$ after a dozen iterations and $k=0.001$ gives $p \approx 0.09107$ after twenty.